# Multiple Environments Multiple S3

Tags: s3

Hi is there a way that we can manage the S3 bucket and configuration from craft general default config per envirenmont?

We are doing automated deployments to different envirenmonts which migrate the databases but are still manually changing the s3 bucket.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 2):

Currently not, but there probably [should be](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com).

There is already a somewhat related, similar [feature request here](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7179038-cloud-based-asset-sources-should-support-environme).

Answer (score 1):

We created a plugin to help solve this problem:
https://github.com/Firstborn/Craft-CMS-Environment-Settings

This plugin allows you to specify different configurations per environment on a single asset source.